# How to make javascript send ajax data once page has loaded without button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have some data that I want to be inserted into MySQL via ajax, so far it ONLY sends the data If I include an html form with a submit and press it, all the data stores correctly, but If I remove it and set a timeout it doesn't seem to send the data.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#postingForm').submit(function ()
    {
        browserres  = screen.width + "x" + screen.height;
        var a= $(document).width(), b=$(document).height(), c=$(window).width(), d=$(window).height(), e=screen.width, f=screen.height;

        $(this).prepend('<input type="hidden" name="browserres" value="' + browserres + '">');
        $(this).prepend('<input type="hidden" name="id2" value="'+a+"x"+b+"X"+c+"x"+d+"X"+e+"x"+f+'">');
        $(this).prepend('<input type="hidden" name="user_agent" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; ?>"></input>');
        $(this).prepend('<input type="hidden" name="user_ip" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>"></input>');

        $.post('insertData.php', { browserres, id2, user_agent, user_ip }, function(json) {
            if(json.outcome == 'success') {
                alert('GOOD!')
            } else {
                alert('Data not sent!');
            }
        },'json');
    });
});

<form id="postingForm" action="insertData.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" vaue="submit"></input>
</form>
```

The above sends the data to insertData.php file and inserts everything correctly, but what I'd like to do is remove the html form, and make it so that once a person lands on the page it will wait until the page has loaded and then it will send the data without the page refreshing.. and without the html form..

I've tried the following and I can't seem to get it to work..

### Not Working Either

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    document.forms["myForm"].submit();

    function()
    {
        browserinfo = escape(JSON.stringify(fetch_client_info(), null, '\t'));
        browserres  = screen.width + "x" + screen.height;
        var a= $(document).width(), b=$(document).height(), c=$(window).width(), d=$(window).height(), e=screen.width, f=screen.height;

        $(this).prepend('<form id="postingForm" name="myForm" action="insertData.php" method="post">');
        $(this).prepend('<input type="hidden" name="browserinfo" value="' + browserinfo + '">');
        $(this).prepend('<input type="hidden" name="browserres" value="' + browserres + '">');
        $(this).prepend('<input type="hidden" name="id2" value="'+a+"x"+b+"X"+c+"x"+d+"X"+e+"x"+f+'">');
        $(this).prepend('<input type="hidden" name="user_agent" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; ?>"></input>');
        $(this).prepend('<input type="hidden" name="user_ip" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>"></input>');
        $(this).prepend('</form>');

        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "insertData.php",
            data: browserinfo, browserres, id2, user_agent, user_ip,
            success: function() {

            }
        });
        return false;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your $.post function immediately after document is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function (){

    var browserinfo = escape(JSON.stringify(fetch_client_info(), null, '\t'));
    var browserres  = screen.width + "x" + screen.height;
    var a= $(document).width(), b=$(document).height(), c=$(window).width(), d=$(window).height(), e=screen.width, f=screen.height;

    var data = {
       browserinfo: browserinfo,
       browserres: browserres,
       // ... etc for all your data
    }

    $.post('insertData.php', data, function(json) {
            if(json.outcome == 'success') {
                alert('GOOD!')
            } else {
                alert('Data not sent!');
            }
        },'json');
});
```

Comment: In which way did it not work? What actually happened? Is there any console output in your browser? Are there network requests happening?

Comment: right now all it's saying is "TypeError: b is null"

Comment: Ok that's to do with something else... Perhaps you can make the page available to see

Comment: Thanks will get back to you when I can

Answer (score 1):

You still need to wire up the handler for the form submit BEFORE you trigger submit.

So...

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    document.forms["myForm"].submit(function()
    {
        browserinfo = escape(JSON.stringify(fetch_client_info(), null, '\t'));
        browserres  = screen.width + "x" + screen.height;
        var a= $(document).width(), b=$(document).height(), c=$(window).width(), d=$(window).height(), e=screen.width, f=screen.height;

        $(this).prepend('<form id="postingForm" name="myForm" action="insertData.php" method="post">');
        $(this).prepend('<input type="hidden" name="browserinfo" value="' + browserinfo + '">');
        $(this).prepend('<input type="hidden" name="browserres" value="' + browserres + '">');
        $(this).prepend('<input type="hidden" name="id2" value="'+a+"x"+b+"X"+c+"x"+d+"X"+e+"x"+f+'">');
        $(this).prepend('<input type="hidden" name="user_agent" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; ?>"></input>');
        $(this).prepend('<input type="hidden" name="user_ip" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>"></input>');
        $(this).prepend('</form>');

        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "insertData.php",
            data: browserinfo, browserres, id2, user_agent, user_ip,
            success: function() {

            }
        });
        return false;
    });

    // now submit it
    document.forms["myForm"].submit()

});
```

Comment: Hang on, that's not a jQuery event handler! Won't work as I can now see that your injecting your form into the DOM. Essentially the form needs to exist in the dom, then and only then can you attach an event handler to its submit event, then you can trigger it. If you need me to write something up based on that flow let me know.

Comment: that would be nice as I can't seem to understand it very well.

Comment: apologies for delay, I've had another chance to review and I'm not entirely sure what you hope to achieve. If you need to post data back to your server then you don't really need the form at all? I can't see id2 being set anywhere. You're also emitting data into variables via php that the server knows about and then sending it right back again, why? If you could reply and clearly state the requirement I'd be glad to help further.

Comment: Hey, I was able to do it using var XMLHttpRequest() instead of going with jQuery.

Thank you for your help, it actually helped a lot.